# Unix: C-shell:Disk space checking in Hp-UX

Tags: shell-script, awk

i have 10 devices that using hp-ux and i want to check the disk space in each devices.
my requirement is if the space more than 90%, the info of device ans space will be save to a log.
this is list of device and ip address which i set as variable ipadd:

```
lo1 100.45.32.43
lot2 100.45.32.44
lot3 100.45.32.44
lot4 100.45.32.45
lot5 100.45.32.46 
and so on..
```

this is my script so far :

```
#!/bin/csh -f

set ipaddress = (`awk '{print $2}' "ipadd"`)

set device = (`awk '{print $1}' "ipadd"`)

@ j = 1

while ($j <= $#ipaddress)

echo $ipaddress
set i = 90        # Threshold set at 90%

set max = 100


while ($i <= $max)        

rsh $ipaddress[$j] bdf | grep /dev/vg00 | grep $i% |awk '{   file=substr($6,index($6,"/") + 1,length($6)); print "WARNING: $device[$j]:/" file " has reached " $5 ". Perform HouseKeeping IMMEDIATELY..." >> "/scripts/space." file ".file"}'

@ i++

end

@ j++
end
```

the output after bdf:

```
/dev/vg00/lvol2    15300207 10924582 28566314   79% /
/dev/vg00/lvol4      42529   23786   25510   55% /stand
```

output at terminal after exec the script:

```
100.45.32.43
100.45.32.44
```

output at .file:

```
WARNING: $device[$j]:/ has reached 79%. Perform HouseKeeping   IMMEDIATELY...
```

the question is, 
is it my looping have something wrong cause only iterates one time only because my .file output only show one device only?
And why $device[$j] not come out in .file output?
or awk have problem?

thank you for the advice.

Comment: `$device[$j]` won't come out because it can't be expanded since it is included between the `''` (single quotes) of the `awk` call. Maybe you could consider to rewrite the script in pure AWK. In general [CSH programming is considered harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/)

Comment: oo..i see..what do u mean by pure awk?

Comment: Sorry I meant you could try to write an AWK only script executing the system commands from within the script.

Comment: actually i dont quite understand what you mean..im sorry but can elaborate more how can i proceed with this script?